# Extract UUID value from JSON returned from HTTP reply

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression, json, uuid

I am trying to make a little script in shellscript that takes one serviceUuid from a response and use it.
I just print the server response on a file called final.txt
Now i need to extract the value after "serviceUuid":"

This is the script:

```
uuid=$(curl   -X POST -H "ACCEPT-LANGUAGE:en"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -H "Accept: application/json" -d  {"username":"HereThereIsTheUsername"}  Here there is the url )

echo $uuid >> final.txt
```

this is the response:

```
{"status":{"code":"STATUS_OK","message":"ServiceUUID sent successfully via..."},"body":{"data":{"userApps":{},"username":"HereTheUsername","fullName":"NameOfTheAccountPossessor","lang":"sq","blocked":false,"lastLogin":"2016-10-10T17:19:22","passwordResetUuid":"6147dc32-b72e-450a-8084-2fdb5319a931","userAccessLevel":5,"countDownSeconds":0,"serviceUuid":"7260276c-5c3f-41d3-9329-3603acecb7e5","userAttributes":{},"labelMap":{},"id":"APPUSER00000012","someLabel":"NameOfTheOrganisation"}}}
```

So can someone help me to extract the value?

Comment: Yes,i don't give the url,username or name of the guy so just place everything you want on the fields that i changed.

Comment: What is the response if you use `echo "$uuid"` instead of `echo $uuid`? The whitespace is important if you're going to try and parse JSON from shell. (Remember to [edit this into your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/325181/edit) and format it with the `{}` button...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now i need to extract the value after "serviceUuid"

So, if the variable `$uuid` contains this:

```
echo "$uuid"
{"status":{"code":"STATUS_OK","message":"ServiceUUID sent successfully via..."},"body":{"data":{"userApps":{},"username":"HereTheUsername","fullName":"NameOfTheAccountPossessor","lang":"sq","blocked":false,"lastLogin":"2016-10-10T17:19:22","passwordResetUuid":"6147dc32-b72e-450a-8084-2fdb5319a931","userAccessLevel":5,"countDownSeconds":0,"serviceUuid":"7260276c-5c3f-41d3-9329-3603acecb7e5","userAttributes":{},"labelMap":{},"id":"APPUSER00000012","someLabel":"NameOfTheOrganisation"}}}
```

...and you **only** want the `serviceUuid` value, I would do this:

```
echo "$uuid" | sed -nE 's/.*"serviceUuid":"(.*)","user.*/\1/p'
7260276c-5c3f-41d3-9329-3603acecb7e5
```

In your case, it would look like:

```
echo "$uuid" | sed -nE 's/.*"serviceUuid":"(.*)","user.*/\1/p' >> final.txt
```

...to append it to the file `final.txt`

---

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

Comment: Another little question about this...now i need to use the value extracted (serviceUuid) and to paste it on the script below:


login=$(curl -X POST -H "ACCEPT-LANGUAGE:en"   -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip"   -H "Accept: application/json" -d  {"serviceUuid":"Here"} ServerUrl)

(it's everything inside the file aass.sh)

Comment: Since that is a new operation it is probably better to ask another question.

Answer (score 3):

[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is a JSON parsing tool. You can do this:

```
uuid=$(curl ...)
service_uuid=$(jq -r '.body.data.serviceUuid' <<<"$uuid")
echo "$service_uuid"
```

```
7260276c-5c3f-41d3-9329-3603acecb7e5
```

Comment: Without the extra fluff: `curl ... | tee final.txt | jq ...`, or forget the `tee` if it's not actually needed (unclear in question).

Answer (score -1):

Don't have 'jq', and have no quote escape problems...
Try this FAST and simple solution...

```
service_uuid=$( grep -oP '"serviceUuid":"\K[^"]+'  <<< "$uuid" )
```

- The `<<< "$uuid` feeds the string into "grep"
- The -oP options mean only the 'matching part' of the perl regex is to be returned.
- The '\K' in the perl-RE means find the part before, but only match the part after.

The result is that it finds the key, and returns the value (up until the first quote).

Fast small simple, and works with a lot of key-value file types.