# Append value as parameter to shell script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, programming, json

I found [the value of a response (curl) with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325181/sh-help-for-a-little-script) and now i need some help to take the value that i printed in a file and to use it in another substring in the same .sh script

This is the response of the server:

```
{"status":{"code":"STATUS_OK","message":"ServiceUUID sent successfully via..."},"body":{"data":{"userApps":{},"username":"HereTheUsername","fullName":"NameOfTheAccountPossessor","lang":"sq","blocked":false,"lastLogin":"2016-10-10T17:19:22","passwordResetUuid":"6147dc32-b72e-450a-8084-2fdb5319a931","userAccessLevel":5,"countDownSeconds":0,"serviceUuid":"7260276c-5c3f-41d3-9329-3603acecb7e5","userAttributes":{},"labelMap":{},"id":"APPUSER00000012","someLabel":"NameOfTheOrganisation"}}}
```

So i finded the value "serviceUuid":

```
fuid=$(echo "$uuid" | sed -nE 's/.*"serviceUuid":"(.*)","user.*/\1/p' >> final.txt)
```

Now i want to take this value(in file final.txt) and to paste it on this string in the same file of the script called aass.sh:

```
login=$(curl -X POST -H "ACCEPT-LANGUAGE:en"   -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip"   -H "Accept: application/json" -d  {"serviceUuid":"**HERE**"} UrlOfTheSite)
```

How i can do?

Comment: If you're using Unix & Linux to do your homework, try organizing a list of questions relating to your script and putting them in the same question, instead of opening a new question for every step of your script, as here, and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325181/extract-uuid-value-from-json-returned-from-http-reply

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only the most recent uuid is stored in final.txt, this should do it...

```
service_uuid=$(cat final.txt)
login=$(curl -X POST -H "ACCEPT-LANGUAGE:en"   -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip"   -H "Accept: application/json" -d  {"serviceUuid":"${service_uuid}"} UrlOfTheSite)
```

Without seeing your whole script it's a little difficult to know exactly what you expect in final.txt, but keep in mind that you're using the append redirect (>>) as opposed to overwrite (>) so that file will probably keep a running list of *all* uuid's the script recieves.